# C# Populating treeview from my XML file, whilst filtering it for no repeats

Tags: c#, collections, treeview, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML file which gets populated programatically when documents are loaded into my program.

What i want to be able to do is create a treeView hierachy using the "system", "subsystem" and "subsubsystem" elements of the XML file.

Also, there will be many instances where the "system" or "subsystem" etc elements are repeated throughout my XML file, so i don't want these to be repeated in my treeView. I need a treeView containing all the system, subsystem and subsubsystem numbers but not repeating itself.

```
<DMs>
  <dataModule>
    <DMC>DMC-AJ-A-21-21-63-00ZZZ-254Z-B_001-00.XML</DMC>
    <techName>Filter assy - blowing</techName>
    <infoName>Clean mechanically</infoName>
    <system>65</system>
    <subsystem>32</subsystem>
    <subsubsystem>12</subsubsystem>
    <status>Checked In</status>
    <notes>-</notes>
    <currentUser>-</currentUser>
    <validator>-</validator>
    <dateMod>-</dateMod>
    <size>-</size>
  </dataModule>
  <dataModule>
    <DMC>DMC-xx-A-21-21-63-00ZZZ-041Z-D_001-00.XML</DMC>
    <techName>Filter assy</techName>
    <infoName>Description of how it is made</infoName>
    <system>21</system>
    <subsystem>15</subsystem>
    <subsubsystem>63</subsubsystem>
    <status>Checked In</status>
    <notes>-</notes>
    <currentUser>-</currentUser>
    <validator>-</validator>
    <dateMod>-</dateMod>
    <size>-</size>
  </dataModule>
  <dataModule>
    <DMC>DMC-xx-A-21-21-63-00ZZZ-042Z-D_001-00.XML</DMC>
    <techName>Filter assy - blowing</techName>
    <infoName>Description of function</infoName>
    <system>21</system>
    <subsystem>15</subsystem>
    <subsubsystem>63</subsubsystem>
    <status>Checked In</status>
    <notes>-</notes>
    <currentUser>-</currentUser>
    <validator>-</validator>
    <dateMod>-</dateMod>
    <size>-</size>
  </dataModule>
  <dataModule>
    <DMC>DMC-xx-A-21-21-63-00ZZZ-066Z-D_001-00.XML</DMC>
    <techName>Filter assy - blowing</techName>
    <infoName>Support equipment and tools data</infoName>
    <system>32</system>
    <subsystem>10</subsystem>
    <subsubsystem>01</subsubsystem>
    <status>Checked In</status>
    <notes>-</notes>
    <currentUser>-</currentUser>
    <validator>-</validator>
    <dateMod>-</dateMod>
    <size>-</size>
  </dataModule>
</DMs>
```

I've got the following method which I think i'm going in the right direction with, but it's getting the system numbers into a collection and sorting them to pass to my method which i'm struggling to know how to do.

```
public void buildTreeView(string sys, string subsys, string subsubsys)
        {
            try
            {
                TreeNode system = treeView1.Nodes.Add("System");
                system.Nodes.Add(sys);
                TreeNode subsystem = system.Nodes.Add("Subsystem");
                subsystem.Nodes.Add(subsys);
                TreeNode subsubsystem = subsystem.Nodes.Add("Subsubsystem");
                subsubsystem.Nodes.Add(subsubsys);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error" + e);
            }

        }
```

Any help appreciated.

What i'm looking to end up with is a chapter numbering system that i can drill down though in the treeView i.e.

```
+ System - 65
        + Subsystem - 32
          Subsystem - 68
                       + Subsubsystem - 01
                         Subsubsystem - 02

+ System - 70
        + Subsystem - 22
          Subsystem - 30
                       + Subsubsystem - 01
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have a working version of code that takes care of your requirement.
The trick is to check whether the node already exists and add to that instead of creating a new node everytime.
We do the tree view generation in steps

1. Get a List of Mappings from XML

2. Generate TreeView by iterating through the mapping List

Notes :

1. This code can be optimized further, but I would leave that to you

2. `treeView1` refers to an object of type `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView`

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initalizes Tree View
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeTreeView()
    {
        var mappingList = ReadXmlData();
        BuildTree(mappingList);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads Mappings from xml file to a List
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<Mapping> ReadXmlData()
    {
        var mappingList = new List<Mapping>();
        var reader = new XmlTextReader(@"D:\data.xml");
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            reader.ReadToFollowing("system");
            string system = reader.ReadString();
            reader.ReadToFollowing("subsystem");
            string subSystem = reader.ReadString();
            reader.ReadToFollowing("subsubsystem");
            string subSubSystem = reader.ReadString();
            mappingList.Add(new Mapping() { _system = system, _subSystem = subSystem, _subSubSystem = subSubSystem });
        }
        return mappingList;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds Tree
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mappingList"></param>
    private void BuildTree(List<Mapping> mappingList)
    {
        foreach (var mapping in mappingList)
        {
            var systemNode = FindNode(mapping._system, NodeType.System);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(systemNode.Text))
            {
                string nodeText = NodeType.System.ToString() + " - " + mapping._system; ;
                systemNode.Text = nodeText;
                systemNode.Name = nodeText;
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(systemNode);
            }

            var subSystemNode = FindNode(mapping._subSystem, NodeType.SubSystem);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(subSystemNode.Text))
            {
                string nodeText = NodeType.SubSystem.ToString() + " - " + mapping._subSystem;
                subSystemNode.Text = nodeText;
                subSystemNode.Name = nodeText;
                systemNode.Nodes.Add(subSystemNode);
            }

            var subSubSystemNode = FindNode(mapping._subSubSystem, NodeType.SubSubSystem);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(subSubSystemNode.Text))
            {
                string nodeText = NodeType.SubSubSystem.ToString() + " - " + mapping._subSubSystem;
                subSubSystemNode.Text = nodeText;
                subSubSystemNode.Name = nodeText;
                subSystemNode.Nodes.Add(subSubSystemNode);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an existing node from the treeview other-wise returns a new node
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private TreeNode FindNode(string data, NodeType type)
    {
        string text = type.ToString() + " - " + data;
        if (treeView1.Nodes.Find(text, true).FirstOrDefault() != null)
        {
            return treeView1.Nodes.Find(text, true).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            return new TreeNode();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class for Mapping
    /// </summary>
    public class Mapping
    {
        public string _system;
        public string _subSystem;
        public string _subSubSystem;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Type of Node
    /// </summary>
    public enum NodeType
    {
        System = 0,
        SubSystem = 1,
        SubSubSystem = 2
    }
```